# Two UIDatePickers (Time mode) - How to tell if they are atleast 3 minutes apart?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

I have two `UIDatePickers`(Time mode) in my project and I'd like to know how to check if the times in the two `UIDatePicker` are atleast, for example, 3 minutes apart. This is probably an easy question but I'm still learning, hope you guys understand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the two `NSDate` values from the pickers. Then do:

```
NSDate *date1 = // first date
NSDate *date2 = // second date
NSTimeInterval diff = fabs([date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2]);
if (diff > 3 * 60) {
    // the difference is more than 3 minutes
}
```

Another options would be:

```
NSDate *date1 = // first date
NSDate *date2 = // second date
unsigned int unitFlags = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:date1  toDate:date2  options:0];
int minutes = [comps minute];
if (minutes > 3) {
    // the difference is more than 3 minutes
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm able to detect it now.